# WSO2 example error - Must Understand Check Failed

Tags: apache, windows-server-2008, wso2

I'm setting up a test lab to learn a bit more about the WSO2 apps. I'm trying to re-create the scenario described here: http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/2012/12/providing-xacml-fine-grained-authorization-webapps

I'm using a single Windows 2008 server and have the WSO apps all listening on different ports. The tryit feature of WSOIS shows the policy is being correctly evaluated. However, when attempting to use the web service I receive a Must Understand Check Failed 500 error.

The full text of the error is below

I've re-created the setup and I get the same error.

> TID[-1234] [AS] [2013-04-25 21:36:37,740] ERROR
>   {org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine} - Must Understand check failed
>   for header
>   http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd
>   : Security
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.checkMustUnderstand(AxisEngine.java:104)
>   org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:170)
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:356)
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
>   org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
>   org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.stub.EntitlementServiceStub.getDecision(EntitlementServiceStub.java:1108)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.soap.basicAuth.BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.getDecision(BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.java:191)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.soap.basicAuth.BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.getDecision(BasicAuthEntitlementServiceClient.java:62)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.PEPProxy.getDecision(PEPProxy.java:78)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.PEPProxy.getDecision(PEPProxy.java:122)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.proxy.PEPProxy.getDecision(PEPProxy.java:99)
>   org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.filter.EntitlementFilter.doFilter(EntitlementFilter.java:185)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:581)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:177)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:161)
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
>   org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
>   org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1653)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: I'm having very similar issue, but the error occurs from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

The root cause is you are setting mustunderstand header in the soap message, so SOAP processor process it and fails because of a missing requirement. You can go through the following [article](http://wso2.org/library/tutorials/understand-famous-did-not-understand-mustunderstand-header-s-error) fro more clarification